# How to set the default "Show as expanded" to true in a custom menu item

Tags: theming, 8

I am creating a series of menus in a custom module. This site also has a custom theme. Is there a way in the theme, or in the module, to set a menus "Show as expanded" to true. This way, if I move my site, uninstall, or whatever, it comes back the way it should right out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find it anywhere on the Drupal documentation, but adding

```
expanded: TRUE
```

in the module.links.menu.yml file works.

Answer (score -1):

According to Drupal API for hook_menu:

> "**expanded**": Optional. If set to TRUE, and if a menu link is provided for this menu item (as a result of other properties), then the menu link is always expanded, equivalent to its 'always expanded' checkbox being set in the UI.

So while writing your custom hook simply add `expanded` option.

```
$items['examples/page_example'] = array(
    'title' => 'Page Example',
    'page callback' => 'page_example_description',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'expanded' => TRUE,
  );
```

Comment: The question seems to be for Drupal 8, but your answer is specific to Drupal 7.